# tSQL: Increase every group by 1

Tags: t-sql, aggregate-functions

Dear Forum and SQL specialists,

is it possible by SQL to increase every group change by 1?
I already tried the agg functions like Dense_Rank, Row_Number ... but without success.

Example:

[image: GroupNumber should be calculated via SQL]

Here you can find some test data

```html
DECLARE   @test  TABLE ([Session]  int, Sort int)
Insert into @test Values (1,1)
Insert into @test Values (1,2)
Insert into @test Values (1,3)
Insert into @test Values (0,4)
Insert into @test Values (0,5)
Insert into @test Values (1,6)
Insert into @test Values (1,7)
Insert into @test Values (1,8)
Insert into @test Values (1,9)
Insert into @test Values (1,10)
Insert into @test Values (1,11)
Insert into @test Values (1,12)
Insert into @test Values (1,13)
Insert into @test Values (0,14)
Insert into @test Values (1,15)
Insert into @test Values (0,16)
Insert into @test Values (1,17)
Insert into @test Values (1,18)
Insert into @test Values (1,19)
Insert into @test Values (1,20)
select * from @test
```

Comment: Please include the expected output.

Comment: Hallo @TimBiegeleisen, the expected output is in the image (column Groupnumber). This should be calculated, based on the column Session

Comment: SQL Tables are unordered set. You must include a column to order the result and to get your expected output.

Comment: Hi @AnkitBajpai ... I have added a sort column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions:

```
SELECT SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY Sort) GroupNumber, Session, Sort
FROM (
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN Session = LAG(Session) OVER (ORDER BY Sort) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END flag
  FROM @test
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92f54116b81313649118605b94ec47b8).

Comment: That's so cool. Thanks a lot for your help!